# MDX query axis [dimension].[dimension].[dimension] behaving differently for different dimensions

Tags: ssas, mdx

In the SSAS AdventureWorks cube -- I don't understand why some dimensions can go directly on a query axis and others can't.

For example, this works perfectly well:

```
Select [Measures].[Internet Sales-Sales Amount] on Columns,
[Sales Reason].[Sales Reason].[Sales Reason] on Rows
From [Analysis Services Tutorial];
```

This doesn't give an error, but only provides a single value for all customers, not grouping by customer as I'd expect:

```
Select [Measures].[Internet Sales-Sales Amount] on Columns,
[Customer].[Customer].[Customer] on Rows
From [Analysis Services Tutorial];
```

I'm not understanding what's different about the Customer dimension that makes it behave differently than the Sales Reason dimension.  Where should I be looking?

Comment: Check the dimension usage tab in the AW cube solution. Since I'm not near my system, can't verify, but I strongly suspect that there is no relation between 'Customer' and 'FactInternetSales'.

Comment: There is in fact a relationship - DimCustomer and FactInternetSales are linked by the Full Name attribute, which is the key on the Customer dimension

Answer (score 0):

In plain AdvWrks I don't see a measure `[Measures].[Internet Sales-Sales Amount]` so I can't replicate the behaviour you mention.

In `AdvWrks` I can do these similar queries:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0
 ,[Customer].[Customer].[Customer] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Gives this:

[image]

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0
 ,[Sales Reason].[Sales Reason].[Sales Reason] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

[image]

Maybe the cube you are using `[Analysis Services Tutorial]` has limited functionality and is only set up to address certain tutorials. Do you have the full `AdvWrks` cube to play with?

Answer (score 0):

#facepalm

It turned out that in my project, after going through some of the tutorials, the identity/key attribute was renamed to `[Full Name]`.  So, `[Customer].[Customer].[Customer]` does not work, but `[Customer].[Full Name].[Full Name]` does.